# Show that for the sum of two exponential distributions, $f(x) = e^{-3x} + \frac{10}{3} e^{-5x}, x>0$

Tags: self-study, distributions, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution, joint-distribution

Claims can be of two types: "severe" or "light"

$$\text{severe claims ~ } \exp(\lambda = 3)$$
$$\text{light claims ~ } \exp(\lambda = 5)$$

The insurer has established that two thirds of all claims are "light" and the rest are "severe". Let $f(x)$ denote the probability density function of any claim payment.

Show that:

$$f_X(x) = e^{-3x} + \frac{10}{3} e^{-5x}, x>0$$

Now suppose:

A = severe claims

B = light claims

$$f_A(a) = 3e^{-3a}, a>0$$
$$f_B(b) = 5e^{-5b}, a>0$$

It appears that they have just taken:

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{3}f_A(a) + \frac{2}{3}f_B(b)$$

I cannot see where this comes from. Here is what I tried:

Let $X= \frac{1}{3}A + \frac{2}{3}B$

$$F_X(x) = P[X \leq x]$$

$$=P[\frac{1}{3}A + \frac{2}{3}B \leq x]$$

$$=P[A \leq 3x - 2B]$$

Now using the Law of Total Probability

$$F_X(x)=\int_0 ^{\infty} P[A = 3x - 2B | B=b] P[B=b] db$$

$$=\int_0 ^{\infty} F_A(3x-2b) f_B(b) db$$

$$=\int_0 ^{\infty} [1 - e^{-3(3x-2b)}] 5e^{-5b} db$$

$$F_X(x)=5\int_0 ^{\infty} [e^{-5b} - e^{b - 9x}]db$$

Now, regardless of whether I try to integrate this or differentiate first with respect to x, I always have the problem that:

$$\lim_{b \to \infty} e^b = \infty$$

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag (and read its wiki)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should integrate

$\int_{b=0}^{b=1.5x}$

instead of $\infty$, since the probability is zero for $b>1.5x$.

---

Aside from that issue, I believe you are adding the claims and probability of claims wrongly. $P[X \leq x] = P[severe]P[A \leq x] + P[light]P[B \leq x] = \frac{1}{3}*P[A \leq x] + \frac{2}{3}P[light]P[B \leq x]$.

But nice work on your convolution operation. What you were trying to calculate is the probability that the weighted sum of a severe claim and a light claim is less than or equal to X.

---

## comparison with throwing dice

Imagine as comparison a random throw of 6 sided (light) dices and 12 (severe) dices. What is the probability of particular throw being $X$ if the probability of a light dice is 2/3 and the probability of a severe dice is 1/3? The answer is of course 2/3 p(dice_light=X) + 1/3 p(dice_severe=X).

What you were trying to calculate is the probability of the weighted sum ($\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$) of two such dices is a. For such calculation you have to do that integral thingy you are working out. (or with dices it is easier and you count the cases)

Comment: In addition. Your integral stuff with the $3x-2b$ term as function parameters won't work out (you need to use it as the integration boundaries). You should evaluate the following $\int_{b=0}^{b=2x} \left( \int_{a=0}^{a=3x-2b} 5 e^{-5a} 3 e^{-3b}    da \right) db$. This is the integral $\int \int 5 e^{-5a} 3 e^{-3b} da db$ on the domain 1/3a+2/3b<x. If you place this '1/3a+2/3b<x'-stuff as parameters then the integration constants 5 and 3 are not correct anymore.